# Speaking to a Rabbi in the Third Person

Tags: halacha, rabbis, derech-eretz-manners

Is there a source for requiring one to refer to his Rabbi in the third person and not referring to a rabbi in the second person (i.e. "you")?

I can not recall any reference to this requirement  in Halacha and have been told that it stems from Yiddish where there are 2 ways of saying "you".

Regarding a parent this [has been asked before](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23149/referring-to-parent-in-third-person), but no halachic source is cited.

Note that every bracha begins with "Baruch atah" which is not third person! If we talk to Hashem in second person it would seem counterintuitive that a rabbi would be stricter.

Comment: I recently saw a source cited in a responsum near the beginning of *She-eilas Aharon* Vol. 1, by R' Aaron Felder [ZTz"L](http://articles.philly.com/2014-05-07/news/49664487_1_rabbi-dov-brisman-scholar-synagogue) that said that one must address one's Rabbi *in plural*. Unfortunately, I don't remember the source or have that volume in front of me right now.

Comment: here is a discussion with a source http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=4825

Comment: In extremely formal Modern Hebrew, one uses the third person. However, given the general Israeli disdain for formality, you might never hear this at any point unless you watch Supreme Court arguments. Yiddish uses the plural "you" (ir) for formal "you." The MH usage is likely related somehow, but I'm not exactly sure in what way.

Comment: @Tatpurusha the Modern Hebrew usage might come from the French instead.  @Yoni - `atah` is second person, but after `asher` or `ha` we're back in third person.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman you're correct. Rav Tzadok in tzidkas hatzadik makes your point..but it points out that 2nd person is not assur.

Comment: @Danno All they quote is the Rambam who never uses third person.

Comment: @msh210 I thought bounties were to find new answers because the old ones are insufficient. How does this work exactly?

Comment: @Matt, one of the reasons to choose among when offering a bounty is "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty".

Comment: @Yoni Regarding your note on our manner of addressing G-d -- Not only do we not use the third person for G-d; we do not even use the second-person plural. Rather, we use the same familiar form as we do with intimate friends. The same is true of a few other relationships where unidirectional respect is exiged, particularly those characterized by love in addition to respect: child--parent, wife--husband, and even chosid--Rebbe at one time. Therefore, it is not surprising that we use this form for G-d, the First and Last Claimant to our love and respect

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This practice seems to be (at least) as old as the Gemara, as the Gemara states in Brachos 27b:

> 'R. Yirmiah b. Abba is different, because he was a
>   disciple-colleague. [This can be proven by the fact that] R. Jeremiah
>   b. Abba said to Rav: Have you made havdalah? He replied: Yes, I
>   have; and he did not say to him, has the master made havdalah'

In other words, the Gemara proves that R. Yirmiyah was a talmid-chaver, or disciple-colleage, of Rav, because a student/disciple would have addressed his teacher in the third person. There are other instances in the Gemara as well where students referred to their teachers as 'mar', in third person.

It's worth pointing out that the early books of halakha (as in, the Rif, Rambam, Rosh, Tur, Shulchan Aruch) do not mention this at all, and this might be merely the proper practice but not strictly obligated. Taz (Y.D. 242:14), however, does quote this as the halacha. His father in law, the Bach (Y.D. 242:6) seems to believe that while such a practice is appropriate, it is not an absolute requirement, and therefore if one is having an extended conversation with one's teacher, the second person may be used after the first time the teacher is addressed.

In addition, as noted in the comments, many languages, including German (and to some extent, Spanish, Portuguese, and Swedish) have an 'honorific' grammatical form which makes use of the third person even when the subject is being addressed directly. [The Wikipedia article on the subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction) includes [Hebrew as an example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction#Hebrew).

Comment: Great Job! Yishar Kochacha!